# rotating list per refreshing page

Tags: php, html

Lets say there are three rows of information that loads on a site, and on the site, you only want 1 of the 3 rows to load each time the page gets refreshed, so it probably should be sorted by random or something better. what is the best code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Go for [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
<?php
$arr=array("Offer 1","Offer 2","Offer 3");
$val=array_rand($arr,1);
echo $arr[$val];
```